# OS X Server Snow - how to abort installation process?

Tags: installation, osx-snow-leopard, restore, snow-leopard-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OS X Sever Snow - how to abort installation process?](https://superuser.com/questions/395135/os-x-sever-snow-how-to-abort-installation-process)

Here is the story... I wasn't aware that "OS X Server" was an actual operating system to install, I thought (seriously!) it's just another application or bunch of apps working nicely together under the OS X Snow Leopard. Because I was struggling with my imap, pop and smtp servers to install locally for last 24 hrs, my mate dropped me the "OS X Server" dmg over the LAN to try it out if this is what I need. So I've installed the package from dmg file then opened the Server Admin app. Nothing was detected, no servers, so I've run this command (don't remember exactly): sudo launchctl load -w /(...).plist The local server seem to appear on the list and I begin to investigate further.. (I already had running Apache, mysql, postfix) and I expected this to appear on the list etc. .. when prompted for serial number I skipped this step (to see more options) by clicking "Save" button and then my machine restarted without any prompt. The OS X Server process began. I realised quickly it's not the action I want to take. Now here is the trick... How do I roll back to my normal Snow Leopard? I know it's there (I've checked from terminal using my original Snow Leopard installation disc) and seems like all data are there. I have time-machine backup but probably 3 weeks old and some significant changes were made since then I don't want to loose. Whenever I boot my macbook (from HDD), it starts the Server installation process, but I haven't done anything yet. Is there a special boot record or something like this where I can force it to start from my previous location? How do I get rid of this?

I simply don't want to install new os and cancel the current process but this thing sits on my drive. Please help, any advice will be great.